# How to force windows to use assigned static IP and not allow default IP to be used?

Tags: windows, networking, ip

I recently changed my windows IP address to 172.16.115.X and the default gateway address is 172.16.112.1. So I got a warning that the gateway and my address are not in the same subnet, which is fine. I ignored the warning because that is the configuration in my lab.

But how do I **not** let/allow windows to use the **default ip** which is 169.X.X.X (something like that). How do I force windows to use the assigned IP?

Comment: To disable [APIPA](www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/APIPA.html) , you need to modify registry. [Ref 1](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_tcpip_pro_disableautoconfiguration.mspx?mfr=true) [Ref2](http://www.davidlprowse.com/article-registry-apipa.php).

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1243175/what-is-ipv4-autoconfiguration-and-why-it-overwrites-static-ip

Answer (score 1):

169.254.0.0/16 is used for IPv4 address autoconfiguration, and is specified as such by [RFC 3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927). See also the [Wikipedia article on link-local IPv4 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv4).

Microsoft calls it "Automatic Private IP Addressing". It may also be called "auto-IP" or by its abbreviation APIPA.

Disabling APIPA will prevent Windows from locally assigning link-local IP addresses to network interfaces.

To disable APIPA, and thus prevent Windows from assigning a 169.254.0.0/16 IPv4 or fe80::/10 IPv6 address to network interfaces where no working IP configuration methods exist, you can refer to [Microsoft KB article 244268](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/244268). In short:

1. Use the registry editor (running as administrator) to navigate to either HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\*adaptername* (a single network adapter) **or** HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters (the entire computer).
2. Create or edit a DWORD value named `IPAutoconfigurationEnabled` and set its value to `0`. A value of 0 indicates that *APIPA is disabled*.
3. Reboot your system.

To restore the default, delete the IPAutoconfigurationEnabled value. To explicitly state the current default (that you want APIPA enabled), set the value to 1.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer contain some wrong informations:

Windows APIPA is only for IPv4 and only IPv4 169.254.x.x addresses can cause troubles.

There is no need to disable IPv6 link local address and doing so would break many IPv6 mechanism.

Fortunately, the keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\ are only linked to IPv4 so disabling APIPA can't break IPv6.